# Yelp Web Scraping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook

When running my code on Jupyter notebook, I ran across this error. I installed `matplotlib` and `pandas`. Does anyone know what it could be?
Code:

```
def average_words(x):
   words = x.split()
   return sum(len(word) for words in word) / len(words)
df['average_word_length'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: average_words(x))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-102-bbc583af9f13> in <module>
----> 1 df['average_word_length'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: average_words(x))

/opt/anaconda3/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3846             else:
   3847                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3848                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   3849 
   3850         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-102-bbc583af9f13> in <lambda>(x)
----> 1 df['average_word_length'] = df['review'].apply(lambda x: average_words(x))

<ipython-input-96-4f4dfe065b11> in average_words(x)
      1 def average_words(x):
      2    words = x.split()
----> 3    return sum(len(word) for words in word) / len(words)

NameError: name 'word' is not defined
```

To be clear, I'm trying to do Web Scraping from Yelp's Website

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

NameError: name 'word' is not defined. You are trying to access word, but word is obviously not defined.

**Possible Solution:**

I think the correct return statement is like this:

`return sum(len(word) for word in words) / len(words)`

(I switched the **word** and **words** in `for word in words`, because I assume that words is the array and not word)